# What's a word/phrase like "compulsion" or "addiction" that is more about guilt than physiology or anxiety?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This question came about because there has been an drought in our area, which is resolved for now, and I am beginning to stop practicing some water-saving measures, but feel discomfort or guilt at no longer doing them. Example sentence:

> I know the drought is over, but I still have a(n) _______ to put a bucket in the shower, and use that water to flush the toilet.

"[Compulsion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compulsion)" (Merriam-Webster) isn't quite right, because there's no strong desire to do the behavior, and no force compelling me to do so--it's more the feeling that the *lack* of doing the behavior causes.

"[Addiction](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/addiction)" (Merriam-Webster) is also not right, because there's no devotion or surrender to a habit known to be bad, and no physiological component.

"Urge" is not quite right either. I do have the [a strong need or desire to have or do](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/urge) something (Merriam-Webster again), but "urge" misses the sense of guilt that occurs when I do not do the behavior.

[This ELU Stack Exchange post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287400/word-for-something-like-an-addiction-that-you-dont-miss-or-crave-when-its-actu) has some good ideas, such as "fixation" and "absorption," but they all involve an aspect of attending to something to the exclusion of other things, which is not the case here.

Of course this may be one of those cases where [I would like for there to be a word for something, but there is not](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/356868/is-there-a-word-for-the-feeling-that-there-ought-to-be-a-word-for-something/357426#357426), but if someone has a word or phrase to encompass this feeling, I would love to hear it.

Comment: "I still have a *residual guilt* not to put ..."

Comment: Similarly, "I still *feel a habitual need* to put a bucket in the shower, and use that water to flush the toilet.

Comment: Ah, but there *is* a strong desire to do the behavior, and there *is* a force that makes you feel **compelled** to do so. They're called [social mores](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/22651/9910).

Comment: I'm with Mazura on this: compulsion is the correct word. Most people with compulsions feel guilt if they don't do them, however unfounded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might like ***compunction***

Defined by [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compunction) as:

> 1
>   a :  anxiety arising from awareness of guilt < compunctions of conscience >
>     b :  distress of mind over an anticipated action or result < showed no compunction in planning devilish engines of … destruction — Havelock Ellis >
>
> 2
>   :  a twinge of misgiving

And by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/compunction) as:

> 1. a feeling of uneasiness or anxiety of the conscience caused by regret for doing wrong or causing pain; contrition; remorse.
> 2. any uneasiness or hesitation about the rightness of an action.

Comment: This is likely what I'm looking for. My first thought was that "compunction" is typically used with negation or a diminisher such as "little"  before it (e.g. "I had no compunction about ___.") I went through the Corpus of Contemporary  American English (http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) and found 137 instances, and all but 15 were preceded by "no," "without," "little," etc. The remainder (except from religious texts) fit my question well, though. So though it generally seems to be used in the negative, I am pretty sure this is what I am looking for:
"I still have a compunction to" etc. Thank you!

Comment: @KatherineLockwood I think your original thought is correct; also, *compunction* seems most often to be uncountable. So rather than *I still feel **a** compunction **to** put a bucket in the shower* etc., I think it would be more usual to  say *I still feel **some** compunction **about not** putting a bucket in the shower...* Still a right answer, I think.

Comment: @1006a, yes, I think putting "some" before it makes it sound better. Interestingly, when I looked more closely at the examples in the [corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), a lot of the examples that were not negated were from the bible or other religious texts. But I think this word definitely works. Thanks for your addition.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [hang-up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hang-up) [MWD]

> something that causes you to feel worried, afraid, embarrassed, etc.

Alternatively, you could use *feeling of [obligation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obligation)* [TFD]

> A social, legal, or moral requirement, such as a duty, contract, or promise, that compels one to follow or avoid a particular course of action

You could say

> I know the drought is over, but I still have a hang-up about putting a bucket in the shower, and using that water to flush the toilet.

or

> I know the drought is over, but I still have a feeling of obligation to put a bucket in the shower, and use that water to flush the toilet.

Comment: Did you see that _obligation_ was [already provided as an answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/359261/173817) before your's?

Comment: Yes but I'm suggesting *feeling of obligation*, which is subjective, not *obligation*

Answer (score 2):

You should consider ***obligation*** (optionally preceded with *moral*).

M-W:

> **[obligation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obligation)**
>   *noun*
>
> : something that you must do because of a law, rule, promise, etc.
>
> : **something that you must do because it is morally right**
>
> She believes that all people have a *moral **obligation*** to defend
>   human rights.
>
> He argues that people in a community have certain ***obligations*** to
>   each other.

Comment: The phrase he gave would become "I still feel an obligation" instead of "I still have an obligation"..

Comment: @BillK, what's wrong with _have_? Did you see the examples from M-W that I gave?

Comment: Having an obligation is a very specific situation--it implies that it's not optional.  If you have an obligation to save water than there are specific active requirement.  Once the requirement has passed, you feel you have an obligation.  In a way feeling that you have an obligation is stronger than having one because if you have an obligation to save water it's out of your control, if you feel you have one then you are choosing to do it to help others or out of your own desire to help.

Answer (score 2):

How about *in good conscience*, properly inserted into your example?

> [*in good
>   conscience*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/conscience): without
>   feeling guilty

Your example:

> I know the drought is over, but I still cannot *in good conscienc*e stop
>   putting a bucket in the shower and using that water to flush the
>   toilet.

Answer (score 1):

"I still have a **drive** to put a bucket in the shower, and use that water to flush the toilet."

> - (Psychology) "A strong motivating tendency or instinct related to self-preservation, reproduction, or aggression that prompts activity toward a particular end." **[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drive)**
> - "an impelling culturally acquired concern, interest, or longing, an urgent, basic, or instinctual need"  [**MW**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to other great answers, if *saving water* preoccupies or intrudes on your mind consistently, you could consider using "[obsession](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/obsession)" which means

> an irrational motive for performing trivial or repetitive actions,
>   even against your will

The word might sound too strong for your context, but I think it is a better choice than compunction.

[Vocabulary.com]

Comment: You can have a compunction **to do** something. But you can't have an obsession **to do** something. So your answer would not fit the OP's sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The previously proposed *feeling of obligation* can be improved as @BillK suggested, to just *obligation*:

> I know the drought is over, but I still *feel an obligation* to put a bucket in the shower, and use that water to flush the toilet.

A variant of this would be *[duty](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/duty)*:

> I know the drought is over, but I still *feel a duty* to put a bucket in the shower, and use that water to flush the toilet.

1. something that one is expected or required to do by moral or legal obligation.
2. the binding or obligatory force of something that is morally or legally right; moral or legal obligation.

You rejected *urge* because it didn't have the guilt part, but I think that the context takes care of that.  However, if you want the feeling of guilt more explicitly present, I suggest

*nagging urge*

> I know the drought is over, but I still have a *nagging urge* to put a bucket in the shower, and use that water to flush the toilet.

Lastly, here is a very informal word that I think would work:

*niggle*

> I know the drought is over, but I still *feel the niggle* to put a bucket in the shower, and use that water to flush the toilet.

The dictionaries say it's only a verb.  But I think you can use it as a noun.  "Niggle" is nice because from the sound, it incorporates "naggging."

If you like this word but want to go by the book, you could say

> I know the drought is over, but I still *feel niggled* to put a bucket in the shower, and use that water to flush the toilet.

(But I would much rather say "feel the niggle.")

Answer (score -2):

I think it depends on the context of the piece you're writing and its style. I like the suggested "hang up". You might try "compelled".